# IIS 7.5 warm up not working with Classic mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, application-pool, autostart, warm-up

IIS 7.5 warm up (IProcessHostPreloadClient) is not working when application pool's Managed Pipeline Mode set to Classic, if the Managed Pipeline Mode set to integrated Mode it works fine.

Not sure if i have to do anything special for classic mode to work

I am following this url

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on our IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). There is a delay about ~30 seconds until the web site appears. We also tried to solve it via ScottGu´s blog with no success. So we installed a cronjob that executes C# code and does a fire-and-forget request to the webserver:

```
public static void WarmUp(string pUrl)
{
    var lWebClient = new WebClient();
    lWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(pUrl , UriKind.Absolute));
}
```

Execute the WarmUp:

```
WarmUp("http://hostname");
```

After that call + ~30 seconds, our web site will appear directly in the browser.